# Customize Popover TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, popover, modalpopup

I am presenting a modal popover view like this:

```
let popover = StatueSelectionController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
popover.delegate = self

popover.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
popover.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
popover.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up;
popover.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 300)
present(popover, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The `popover.delegate = self` has nothing to do with `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` although it does implement that protocol.

The problem is that the popover takes up the whole view. `StatueSelectionController`, which is a `UICollectionViewController`, fills up the whole screen and does not change for `preferredContentSize`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you running this on an iPhone/iPod touch or on an iPad?

Comment: Im running this on IPhone in portrait mode only

Comment: Popovers are not popovers on iPhones. You get the same result as `.fullScreen`. This is mentioned in the documentation for `.popover`.

Comment: Ok, I previously added the collectionview to a subView of the mainView as a childviewcontroller and that was working nicely but I wanted to have the main view dim like how this behavior normally works. Is there a way to get this behavior easily?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the popOver to not cover the full screen on an iPhone, you would have to add a `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` method in your code

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```